# A word for inefficient communicators

Tags: single-word-requests

I work in an office where I routinely deal with clients.

Some clients can tell you what you need to know about the issue that you are being asked to deal with for them in ten minutes with just a handful of follow up questions from the person in my office talking to them.

Other clients may need an hour to communicate the same thing to someone in my office, sometimes less accurately and reliably as well, and often it is necessary to repeat a large share of something a person in my office has previously discussed with that person in a subsequent conversation, because the first one "didn't stick."

These tendencies are usually habitual and persistent. People who I sometimes call "efficient communicators" tend to almost always be efficient communicators. People who I sometime call "inefficient communicators" likewise tend to incurably behave in this manner.

I am looking for a single word that describes a person who is this kind of inefficient communicator.

I do not believe that this question is a duplicate of the question "What is a word to describe inefficient communication?", as that question discusses the activity or transaction in which this happens, rather than describing a characteristic of a person who habitually is inefficient in communicating.

Comment: You mean someone who's bad at listening? Bad at explaining? Or both? Because I'm not sure they're strongly correlated.

Comment: To make this question on-topic, please edit to include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. You might also want to clarify the tone you're looking for ("moron" works, but might not be productive). In fact, I'd suggest that if you're looking for something professional and helpful, it's better to address the behavior than to find a label to "name-call" the person.

Comment: The question is clear as to the context in which the word is needed, and a sample sentence would be otiose. Leave open.

Comment: @Anton The context doesn't seem clear to me. Is this going to be used for internal communication among the support people ("Be warned, So-and-so is an X") or with the client in question ("Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding, you're an X"). The appropriate answer could be very different.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the previous question and answers which are indeed duplicates and that I was unable to find when doing a search.

Answer (score 0):

A few options here:

First, you could just go with "communicators" vs "non-communicators". This is the route I believe I would go with this.

You could label the efficient communicator with some other word and stick "non-" in front as well. The best I can think of off the top of my head is "articulator" (ostensibly, [one who speaks in a clear and effective manner](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/articulate)) - not present in my dictionary, but the meaning is pretty clear.

Finally, you could instead directly label the "inefficient communicators" (your original ask). There're all manner of words for people who talk too much without communicating much, but to answer your specific question, to wit, you could use rambler or circumlocutor. You run a greater risk of offending your clients if this gets out, though (same for these other ones too, I guess, but I feel like this option more-so).

Answer (score 0):

The word that comes immediately to mind is “bloviator,” but it is insulting. [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloviator) defines the term as follows:

> One who habitually bloviates; a pompous, opinionated, typically voluble commentator.

Comment: But circumlocution may just be related to lack of skill in communicating.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed. Most such people are simply incompetent at communicating despite being nice people acting in good faith. A since deleted comment (presumably because it was an answer) suggesting "inarticulate" seems closer to what I am trying to describe.